# MySql "No Database selected", inspite of fully qualified name

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a query in Mysql server

```
DELETE FROM MY_DB.MY_TABLE;
```

But I am getting an error **"No Database selected"**. Why should I explicitly select a DB when I give the complete name, including DB?

Comment: You can jest select it `USE MY_DB; DELETE FROM MY_TABLE;`

Comment: That query works for me. You need to add info about your environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to execute the query from command line, can you try:

```
use MY_DB;
```

It will use MY_DB as default database. [Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html) the documentation for use command. It says the following:

> The USE db_name statement tells MySQL to use the db_name database as
>   the default (current) database for subsequent statements. The database
>   remains the default until the end of the session or another USE
>   statement is issued.

**Update**

If `use` command fails as well, then presumably the user does not have access to `MY_DB`, in which case, you can grant the access by using MySQL's `GRANT` syntax (documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)). You should not need to explicitly `use` the database if you are specifying it in query itself.

Comment: How does that answer: "Why should I explicitly select a DB?"?

Comment: It seems to be a privilege issue. Once I restarted my session it worked!!!